# get and bind from lookup service current year and previous year in c#

Tags: c#

I already have lookup service to get list of years

```
 private void LoadDropDownList()
    {
      ddlTahunPrestasi.DataSource = 
      LookupManager.GetLookupTahunPrestasi(string.Empty);
      ddlTahunPrestasi.DataBind();
      ddlTahunPrestasi.SelectedValue = 
      TahunPrestasiManager.GetSingleRecordFromDate(DateTime.Now).ToString();
    }
```

This is the lookup service

```
public List<LookupModel<string>> GetLookupTahunPrestasi()
    {
        List<LookupModel<string>> list = new List<LookupModel<string>>();

        using (PrestasiEntities context = new PrestasiEntities())
        {
            var entities = from p in context.TahunPrestasis
                           orderby p.startDate descending
                           select new LookupModel<string>
                           {
                               Value = p.tahunPrestasi_PK.ToString(),
                               Text = p.description
                           };

            list = entities.ToList();
        }

        return list;
    }
```

This is TahunPrestasiManager.GetSingleRecordFromDate to default current year when page load

```
public int GetSingleRecordFromDate(DateTime date)
    {
        var entity = this.Context.TahunPrestasis.SingleOrDefault(p => p.startDate <= date && p.endDate >= date);

        if (entity != null)
        {
            var model = new TahunPrestasiModel()
            {
                TahunPrestasi_PK = entity.tahunPrestasi_PK,
                Code = entity.code,
                Description = entity.description,
                StartDate = entity.startDate,
                EndDate = entity.endDate,
                KendiriMark_Ind = entity.kendiriMark_Ind,
                PrestasiSelesai_Ind = entity.prestasiSelesai_Ind,
                SuratKeputusanDate = entity.suratKeputusanDate
            };

            return model.TahunPrestasi_PK;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

and this is the output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHXV6.png)

BUT.. i want the output list of current year and 2 previous year only. note: tahun in english is year.

Comment: Please do not post images or links. Post your code here instead.

Comment: Thank you for telling me..im new here.. i have edited it